# How to use trained deep learning model to predict in excel?

Tags: excel, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, user-defined-functions

After we trained my neural network and saved my model with tensorflow, we can load the model and predict result like following:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
result = model.predict(test_input)
```

Is there any way we can use the trained model in excel to do the similar job? I assume we can build a excel user defined function to take n parameter and give a number. Can we do in VBA? How to load the model file and run the predict?

Comment: Why do not read the excel data and run your model in a script?

Comment: I see excel now(late Aug 2023) supports running python natively. Did you tried or find any solutions for above? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use xlwings (https://www.xlwings.org/) to call python code.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might help:
https://datascienceplus.com/machine-learning-in-excel-with-python/

It's using tensorflow rather than keras, but it shows how you can run your Python code from Excel with PyXLL.

To get your code into Excel you would need to install the PyXLL add-in (https://www.pyxll.com -- commercial software) and then use the @xl_func decorator to expose your Python function to Excel.

This video on calling Python functions from Excel explains more:
https://youtu.be/vyDd_3r93cU